# How to search through Jquery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to loop through an array using contains, but even if the value isnt it there it still appears true.  The array is a list of checkboxes

```js
function CheckBoxLogic(QId, Valuearray, UnCheckedValueArray) {

                var CheckedChildArray = Valuearray;
                var UnCheckedChildArray = UnCheckedValueArray;


             $('.AnswerFunctions').each(function () {
                //Get ParentID from child control
                var ParentQuestionId = $(this).attr('ParentQuestionId');
                //Get ParentValue from child control

                var ParentQuestionValue = $(this).attr('ParentQuestionValue');
                 var QuestionId = $(this).attr('QuestionId');

                if (ParentQuestionId === QId) {
                    if ($(CheckedChildArray + ":contains('" + ParentQuestionValue + "')")) {
                        $('#' + QuestionId + '-Question').removeClass('d-none');
                    }
                    //if ($(UnCheckedChildArray + ":contains('" + ParentQuestionValue + "')")) {
                    //        $('#' + QuestionId + '-Question').addClass('d-none');
                    //    };
                }
            });
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are `CheckedChildArray` and `UnCheckedChildArray`?  Can you provide a complete example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: If `CheckedChildArray` really does contain an array, then your logic is flawed. You need to `filter()` it, or at the very least loop through it and check the values manually. jQuery is not suited to that job; not least because `:contains` is a selector for finding DOM elements.

Comment: Hi David, i have given you the complete function.

Comment: Hi Rory,  I will try your suggestion

Comment: I recommend you get the input attribute data, add them as objects to an array and from there, consult using the array methods that is the simplest way. If you like, share the DOM of the checkboxes nodes to do the exercise

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you loop through an array.  (At its simplest, what exactly do you expect `[] + ":contains('"` to be?  You can't meaningfully concatenate a string and an array like that.)

If you want to check if an array contains a value, you can use [the `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).  For example:

```
if (CheckedChildArray.includes(ParentQuestionValue)) {
    $('#' + QuestionId + '-Question').removeClass('d-none');
}
```